# define a 2D constant array in a C macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I would like to load a static array in memory, used as a convolution kernel in a later loop, in C99 and later. I tried that:

```
/** This is the outer product of
 * filter[5] = { 1.0f / 16.0f, 4.0f / 16.0f, 6.0f / 16.0f, 4.0f / 16.0f, 1.0f / 16.0f };
 * computed at once, outside of the pixels loops, saving 25 multiplications per pixel
 * */
#define filter[5][5] { {0.00390625f, 0.015625f, 0.0234375f, 0.015625f, 0.00390625f}, \
                       {0.01562500f, 0.062500f, 0.0937500f, 0.062500f, 0.01562500f}, \
                       {0.02343750f, 0.093750f, 0.1406250f, 0.093750f, 0.02343750f}, \
                       {0.01562500f, 0.062500f, 0.0937500f, 0.062500f, 0.01562500f}, \
                       {0.00390625f, 0.015625f, 0.0234375f, 0.015625f, 0.00390625f} }
```

GCC 8 complains:

```
error: expected expression before « { » token
 #define filter { {0.00390625f, 0.015625f, 0.0234375f, 0.015625f, 0.00390625f}, \
```

I have found how to load 1D vectors, but how to do that with 2D ?

**Edit**

The ultimate goal is to build a SIMD array from it:

```
static const __m128 filter_sse[5][5] = { { _mm_set1_ps(filter[0][0]),
                                         ... },
                                           ... };
```

and using a `static const float filter[5][5]` makes it complain about trying to set a constant with non-constant values.

Comment: why not just `const float filter[5][5] = ...` ?

Comment: because I need another array with SIMD vectors like `const __m128 filter_sse[i][j] = { _mm_set1_ps(filter[i][j]) }`, and GCC complains I try to set a const with a non-const if I just use a `const float filter[5][5]`

Comment: There cannot be arrays of constrant expressions in C,  your best option would be putting the values directly in the destination initializer  . You could even put the calculations in there rather than the result float constants.

Comment: @M.M I don't want to put the calculation in the loops… that's 25 unnecessary multiplications per pixel, doesn't make sense. I need `const` to avoid false-sharing in parallel loops.

Comment: @AurélienPierre the computation will occur at compile-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You left off the `=` between `filter[5][5]` and `{ {`.

And, as you have it, `filter` can't be be the macro name because it is followed by the brackets

And, you need the type (e.g. `float`)

Here's a cleaned up version:

```
#define DEFME float filter[5][5] = { \
    {0.00390625f, 0.015625f, 0.0234375f, 0.015625f, 0.00390625f}, \
    {0.01562500f, 0.062500f, 0.0937500f, 0.062500f, 0.01562500f}, \
    {0.02343750f, 0.093750f, 0.1406250f, 0.093750f, 0.02343750f}, \
    {0.01562500f, 0.062500f, 0.0937500f, 0.062500f, 0.01562500f}, \
    {0.00390625f, 0.015625f, 0.0234375f, 0.015625f, 0.00390625f} }

DEFME;
```

*Side note:* But, why use a macro for this?

Answer (score 3):

Abstracting from the sense of it

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define myfilter(name) name[5][5] = { {0.00390625f, 0.015625f, 0.0234375f, 0.015625f, 0.00390625f}, \
                       {0.01562500f, 0.062500f, 0.0937500f, 0.062500f, 0.01562500f}, \
                       {0.02343750f, 0.093750f, 0.1406250f, 0.093750f, 0.02343750f}, \
                       {0.01562500f, 0.062500f, 0.0937500f, 0.062500f, 0.01562500f}, \
                       {0.00390625f, 0.015625f, 0.0234375f, 0.015625f, 0.00390625f} }

int main()
{
    const float myfilter(filter1);
    printf("%f\n", filter1[1][1]);

    return 0;
}
```